# Looking for Algorithm Source

Tags: random, taocp

Looking through my 3 volumes of TAOCP I can not find the source of the short random sequence:

```
// Seed always in 1..0x10000
Seed = (Seed * const) % 0x10001
```

There was also a algorithm and possibly a MIX program to validate the const such that all 2^16 values will be returned.  At least that’s what I remember.  Also in the same general area was the fact that the above recursion works because (2^16)+1 is prime but alas, neither (2^32)+1 nor (2^64)-1 are primes.

FWIW, replacing const with iconst = 1/const (mod 0x10001) produces the sequence in reverse order.  I.e. const*iconst%0x10001 = 1

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: The question is: where is this random recursion documented? And what is the algorithm that validates "const" for a full 2^16 sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is a variant of [linear congruential generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)(LCGs) known as a Prime Modulus Multiplicative Linear Congruential Generator (PMMLCG - see Law's "Simulation Modeling and Analysis, 5e" p.400), also sometimes called a [Lehmer generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_RNG).  Both links I've provided give common parameterizations, the first link gives rules for choosing parameters which will give a full cycle.  However, having full cycle is not a sufficient condition to have a good generator, as IBM devastatingly found out with the now infamous [RANDU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANDU).

I strongly urge you to use only algorithms which have been well tested, it's amazingly hard to get this right. There are [well-researched and readily available algorithms](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-number-generator-algorithms.html) that are widely available now which are much better than any LCG.

Comment: Thanks @pjs. I posted in the random section because I somehow remember reading about this kind of generator in TAOCP chapter 3. It’s always nice to credit sources. No $ for Law's “Simulation Modeling and Analysis, 5e”. I found my x86 asm code from 2001 that full range consts. Wish I had made better comments....

However I only need reasonably well scrambled. My intended use is a 16-bit sbox for encryption. Full period implies invertibility. I will ask in stack ovf math department if mod (2^32+1) has multipliers that guarantee a full cycle. This could make a full 32-bit sbox and its inverse.

Comment: Please don't use _any_ type of linear congruential generator for encryption, it's arguably one of the worst PRNG choices you could make! Look at the "Advantages and disadvantages of LCGs" section of the Wikipedia link I provided, 2nd paragraph in particular.